# Design Method to Break Large Class Using Encapsulation

Tags: matlab, class, design-patterns

I have a big data class (`D`) (all in all ~3000 lines). Its purposes can be splited into the following subsections:

- I/O - Read/Write/Import/Create/Copy... (Mostly parsing of binary datafiles and setting up data structures - this part itself accounts for about a third of the code)
- Analysis - About 10 functions to analyze the code without manipulating it (Each function is completely independent of each other but there exist some common helper functions)
- Manipulation - About 10 function to manipulate the data set (The same like for Analysis, no cross interaction between methods except helper functions)
- Visualization - Visualize the data(This is mainly plot one or several datasets into one matlab figure and play around with the axes/cursor/zoom handle - but it needs to store the data onto the figure)
- Common helper functions - Private functions (like input parsing, ...)

I already spitted of Visualization as a separate class (`V`). This mainly for the reason that I can tag all the necessary visualization info onto the `matlab figure` (with `setappdata`) and therefore make the visualization independent of `D`. In order to directly call `V` I created a wrapper within `D`.

My question now is how should I proceed to split up this big class? The only three options I can think of are:

- Transform the methods into functions and put them all in to on folder
- Create static classes to simulate namespaces and order the methods in the same manner like the bullet points.
- Leave the monstrosity be and watch it grow.

Since the first and the last option are fairly straight forward I'll give a little example what I meant by the second:

I have a main class:

```
classdef main < handle
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        analysis
    end

    methods
        function obj = main
           obj.analysis = analysis(obj);

           ...
        end

       ...  
    end
end
```

and the subclasses

```
classdef analysis < handle
    properties(SetAccess = private)
        parent
    end

    methods
        function obj = analysis(parent)
            obj.parent = parent;
        end

        ...
    end
end
```

This would somehow group the methods.

The language is `Matlab` for the case it matters.

Comment: ideally if you have anything variable happening you should create a new class for it. For example I/O is a variable part. Then you can club objects of  all these new classes together in another `D`

Comment: @hyades Let me get sure I understood your comment correctly. You are then in fact suggesting the second option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to splitting up code is ensuring I break things into sensible components. In this case, I'm assuming you're storing a lot of variables. The key here is to functionalize everything and use encapsulation for meaningful abstraction. You can run through this checklist:

- Are there certain functions you consistently use with a bunch of variables? If so, group them into a class.
- Are there certain classes that you use over and over again with minor modifications? If so, use class inheritance.
- Are there certain classes that have a similar structure, but implement functions differently? If so, use abstract classes.
- Don't forget to use local functions and try to vectorize when possible.

In your case, with limited information, I would separate your workflow as follows.

1. I/O Operations, should should probably abstract Read/Write/Import/Create/Copy into methods or more classes (if the code is even more complex than what you described) under a DataReader class
2. Analysis - If each function is similar, create class inheritances. Otherwise, toss it into a DataAnalyzer class and use local functions accordingly.
3. Manipulation - Depending on the precedence of these manipulations, create different levels of Classes for each level of manipulation. Possibly do it all under a DataManipulator class and have getters that get the calculations.
4. Visualization - Similar to Manipulation, also encapsulate into classes for each type of visualization. You can probably encapsulate it all under a DataVisualizer class and have a plot/print function for each figure you're plotting.
5. Regarding Local/Private functions, try to create anonymous functions for simple calculations, local functions if they are more complex. If you find you are using local functions in multiple places, you probably need to redesign your class, feed in a function handle somewhere, or use a private function in a subfolder.

Perhaps if you outline what you are doing and more detailed actions you want to do, I can help further.

**EDIT:** Added some code to exemplify:

I assume your data is not overwritten during manipulation. If it is, just store it in the same variable. If algo1 is the same as algo2, then you can probably do some interconnecting between functions/classes to further reduce code. You can interconnect by using inheritence or calling algo2() from algo1().

script.m

```
D = DataReader.readData( 'file.txt' );
A = DataAnalyzer.analyzeData( D );
M = DataManipulator.manipData( D );
DataVisualizer.plotGraphs( M );
```

DataAnalyzer.m

```
classdef DataAnalyzer
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        ...
    end

    methods
        function obj = DataAnalyzer( D )
           ...
        end

        function A = analyzeData( obj.D )
           A.algo1 = obj.algo1(D);
           A.algo2 = obj.algo2(D);
           ...
        end

        function a = algo1( obj, D );
           ...(algo here)
        end
       ...  
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I'm still a bit lost on what you mean by point 3. So the `superclass` is of the type Analysis with some `subclasses` ana1, ana2, etc which are all properties of the main class? I updated my question a bit to give additional information.

Comment: @magu_ No problem, every programmer needs to have solid encapsulation skills for code maintenance. I updated my answer to give some examples. Depending on the complexity of your algos, you could even further encapsulate them into classes. Let me know if I need to elaborate.

Comment: @magu_ This is an example of one of my object files for my research
http://pastebin.com/iAXHjrch

Comment: @magu_ You can even set permission access to ensure some methods/functions/properties are not accessed outside the intended scope

Comment: @magu_ If this is the solution for you, please accept the answer :) otherwise, let me know if there's anything else I can elaborate on!

Comment: Ah, I think I begin to understand what you mean, so basically I should not use a central knob (from which everything could be called) anymore but let the object be a function input where it gets digested so to say.

Comment: Yup! That's one way of how class encapsulation and functions could work :)

Comment: Obviously this is only one of the many ways your workflow could be setup, but this way makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @magu_ Again I have to insist, if this is the correct solution, kindly mark it as the accepted answer. This will help future users find the right answer :)